# UCSC liftover cannot produce bed format output

Tags: bed, ucsc, liftover

I was trying to use [UCSC liftover tool](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgLiftOver) to convert human coordinates to mouse. While most of the files worked, one file didn't:

```
chr16   86430087    86430726    Human_chr16:86430087-86430726___element_1___positive____neural_tube[12/12]___hindbrain_(rhombencephalon)[12/12]___limb[3/12]___cranial_nerve[8/12]
chr16   85620095    85621736    Human_chr16:85620095-85621736___element_2___negative_
chr16   80423343    80424652    Human_chr16:80423343-80424652___element_3___negative_
chr16   80372593    80373755    Human_chr16:80372593-80373755___element_4___positive____neural_tube[6/10]___hindbrain_(rhombencephalon)[10/10]___midbrain_(mesencephalon)[10/10]
```

Does anyone know why this bed file can only be converted to chr:start-end format but not bed4 format?

Comment: Were there any logged messages during the process?  Can you include an example that did complete the liftover?

Comment: If you remove everything after the "Human" in each line then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue by myself. It turned out that UCSC liftover doesn't like the character ":"

I removed ":" and it worked